# Twig JS (gulp-twig) - Traversing large data structures with DRY principles in mind

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, gulp, twig

## TL;DR

Is there a way of programatically reassigning where a Twig partial reads its data from? I have a blob of JSON that provides the data structure for elements in a pattern library, and need to ensure that Twig serves the correct data to the corresponding `.twig` partial files.

## Background

I've got the following JSON data:

**button.json (simplified)**

```
{
    "element": {
        "button": {
            "attr": {
                "class": "btn"
            },
            "subelement": {
                "span": {
                    "attr": {
                        "class": "btn__text"
                    },
                    "content": {
                        "text": "Button Text"
                    }
                }  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the following Twig templates:

**button.twig (simplified)**

```
{% set base = 'button' %}
{% set el = element[base] %}

<button type="button"
{% include '_partial/_attr.class.twig' %}
>

    {% set el = element[base].subelement.span %}

    {% include 'span.twig' with { el: el } %}
    </span> {# <span> closes here as it could have subsequent elements inside it #}

</button>
```

**span.twig (simplified)**

```
<span
{% include '_partial/_attr.class.twig' %}
>

{% if el.content.text %}
    {{ el.content.text }}
{% endif %}
```

And a Twig partial:

**_attr.class.twig**

```
{% if el.attr.class %}
    class="{{ el.attr.class }}"
{% endif %}
```

The above renders the following HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn">
    <span class="btn__text">Button Text</span>
</button>
```

These files all contribute towards a pattern library where I intend to go fully DRY (hence the partial file (one of many)). I would like to make everything as reusable as possible, so that a `<button>` or a `<span>` could be declared once but used under many different contexts.

## Problem

In `button.twig` I hard-code `{% set el = element[base].subelement.span %}` to change the value of `el` (so that `<span>` gets the correct data). This syntax only works as long as there is only level of `subelement`.

Consider this structure:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-element>
        <label>Label Example</label>
        <input type="text">
    </span>
</form>
```

I'm stumped by how to access the data for `<label>` and `<input>` as all permutations I've tried (e.g. `element[base].subelement.div.subelement.label` and `element[base.subelement.div].subelement.label`) don't work.

What I'm trying to achieve is a reliable way of traversing the data object so that I can have markup structures x elements deep.

My thoughts so far have been:

- Creating the object key reference with a JS function (have had issues getting the returned string back into a Twig object reference)
- Creating a sort of 'tracker' which keeps track of how deep in the data structure I am (again, I'm thinking a JS function that can tell Twig how deep x element is in the data structure)
- Reformatting the data structure so that the hierarchy is expressed another way)
- Am I even correct in reassigning `el` so that it always represents the current element?
- I've also tried using `attribute(base, xxx)` to no avail

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was drastically over-thinking it as Twig has excellent 'content switching' already built in, making use of its `with` statement.

Here's how everything now works...

Firstly, I turned all `subelement` objects into arrays, so my `button.json` file would look like this:

**button.twig (simplified)**

```
{
    "element": {
        "button": {
            "attr": {
                "class": "btn"
            },
            "subelement": [
                {
                    "span": {
                        "attr": {
                            "class": "btn__text"
                        },
                        "content": {
                            "text": "Button Text"
                        }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Then I could do what I called 'context switching' in my twig templates by using something like:

**button.twig (simplified)**

```
{% set root = root.subcomponent[0] %}

{# _button_text_ #}
    {# <span> #}
        {% include '../_partial/_text.span.twig' with { root: root._button_text_ } %}
    </span>
{# /_button_text_ #}
```

The key is to use `with { foo: bar }` with the include as that 'shifts' where in the JSON the component reads its data from. Also, I know that `span` is always going to be `subcomponent[0]` so this is totally safe to use. If required the statement could always be wrapped in a conditional such as:

```
{% if root.subcomponent[0] == '_button_text_' %}
    {% set root = root.subcomponent[0] %}
{% endif %}
```

Or for multiple (repeating) subelements:

```
{% for subcomponent in root.subcomponent %}
    {# _description_list_item_ #}
        {# <div> #}
            {% include '../../../atom/structure/_partial/_structure.division.twig' with { root: subcomponent._description_list_item_ } %}

            {% set root = subcomponent._description_list_item_ %}

            {# _description_term_ #}
                {% include '../../../atom/text/_partial/_text.description-term.twig' with { root: root.subcomponent[0]._description_term_ } %}
            {# /_description_term_ #}

            {# _description_details_ #}
                {% include '../../../atom/text/_partial/_text.description-details.twig' with { root: root.subcomponent[1]._description_details_ } %}
            {# /_description_details_ #}

        </div>
    {# /_description_list_item_ #}

{% endfor %}
```